# ControllerAdvice isn't picking IllegalArgumentException thrown by an incorrect UUID value passed as @RequestParam

Tags: spring-boot, validation, exception, controller, uuid

I have the following controller:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
@Validated
public class HighlightController {
    // ...
    @GetMapping("/highlights")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Highlight>> getHighlights(
            @RequestParam(required = false) UUID impersonateUserId
    ) {
      // ...
```

Then I have the following controller exception handler:

```
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    //...

    @ExceptionHandler(value = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleIllegalArgumentException(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        log.info("Handled: IllegalArgumentException", ex);
        return buildResponseEntity(new ApiErrorResponse(
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                "Incorrect Request",
                ex
        ));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = RuntimeException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleRuntimeException(RuntimeException ex) {
        log.error("Handled: Runtime exception", ex);
        return buildResponseEntity(new ApiErrorResponse(
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                "Internal error",
                ex
        ));
    }
 
    //...

    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(ApiErrorResponse errorResponse) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, errorResponse.getStatus());
    }
```

When I send a request to `v1/highlights` endpoint with an incorrect UUID valie, I would expect that the `IllegalArgumentException` thrown by `StringToUUIDConverter` when parsing UUID from String value would be caught by `handleIllegalArgumentException`, but instead, it is handled by `handleRuntimeException`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call your controller, for example like:

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/highligths?impersonateUserId=x
```

what would be the result? For me it is not `IllegalArgumentException`.

Have a look what I got:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.UUID'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: x
> org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.UUID'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: x

So could it be that you should handle `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException`?

I admit it is a bit confusing that the first lines suggest the cause to be `IllegalArguemntException`.

If I call:

```
localhost:8080/v1/highligths?impersonateUserId=123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-556642440000
```

everything seems to be ok.

If I then call:

```
http://localhost:8080/v1/highligths?impersonateUserId=123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-556642440000x
```

I get:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.UUID'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UUID string too large
> org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.UUID'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UUID string too large

But again, the exception thrown is actually:

```
MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException
```

Comment: Thanks @pirho, that explains it. It is indeed very confusing, especially that even the docs for `UUID fromString()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html say that `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown, hence this is what I was trying to catch in the controller exception handler. The lesson learnt is to read logs more carefully. 

I guess the explanation would be that `IllegalArgumentException` is caught by Spring and rethrown as `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException`?

Comment: Yes. I learnt that lesson when I was implementing JSR-303 annotation validation in controller. It of course never even validated the object when it could not be constructed. The point in wrapping the exception is - I guess - that there can be any kind of exception while constructing the parameter and `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` is just more convenient way to handle those in a more generic way.