# Handling exceptions thrown by object bound to @RequestParam in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, parsing, controller, pojo

Following this article: http://dolszewski.com/spring/how-to-bind-requestparam-to-object/

I created the following controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/highlights")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Highlight>> getHighlights(
            HighlightFilterCriteria highlightFilterCriteria
            ) {
        //...
```

Where HighlightFilterCriteria POJO has the following shape:

```
public class HighlightFilterCriteria {

    private LocalDateTime updatedDate;

    private UUID userId;

    public LocalDateTime getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(String updatedDate) {
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
        try {
            this.updatedDate = LocalDateTime.parse(updatedDate, dateTimeFormat);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException exc) {
            throw new InvalidInputException("udpatedDate", "should be ISO date");
        }
    }

    public UUID getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        try {
            this.userId = UUID.fromString(userId);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exc) {
            throw new InvalidInputException("userId", "should be UUID");
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the implementation of the custom exception I created `InvalidInputException`:

```
package com.hmhco.rcehighlightspoc.exceptionsHandling;

public class InvalidInputException extends RuntimeException {

    private String paramName;
    private String message;

    public InvalidInputException(String paramName, String message) {
        super("\"" + paramName + "\" provided is invalid. It should be " + message);
        this.paramName = paramName;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Then here is the ControllerAdvice implementation with an exception handler for `InvalidInputException` and a generic catch all `Exception` handler:

```
@Slf4j
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = InvalidInputException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidInputException(InvalidInputException ex) {
        log.info("Handled: Invalid input", ex);
        return buildResponseEntity(new ApiErrorResponse(
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                "Incorrect input",
                ex
        ));
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception ex) {
        log.error("Handled: Catch all exception", ex);
        return buildResponseEntity(new ApiErrorResponse(
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                "Catch all exception handler",
                ex
        ));
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(ApiErrorResponse errorResponse) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, errorResponse.getStatus());
    }
```

When I send a request with malformed userId query param (incorrect UUID) `http://localhost:8080/v1/highlights?updatedDate=2020-05-18T08:58:33.876Z&userId=badUUID`, then the try/catch in `HighlightFilterCriteria` captures `InvalidInputException` and rethrows it as my custom `InvalidInputException` but unfortunately, the ControllerAdvice's `handleInvalidInputException` handler for `InvalidInputException` isn't catching it for some reason.

It is caught instead by `@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)` handler, I can see this in the log:

```
ERROR com.hmhco.rcehighlightspoc.exceptionsHandling.GlobalExceptionHandler.handleException - Handled: Catch all exception
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'highlightFilterCriteria' on field 'userId': rejected value [abcacf9b-926a-49c4-b980]; codes [methodInvocation.highlightFilterCriteria.userId,methodInvocation.userId,methodInvocation.java.util.UUID,methodInvocation]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [highlightFilterCriteria.userId,userId]; arguments []; default message [userId]]; default message [Property 'userId' threw exception; nested exception is com.hmhco.rcehighlightspoc.exceptionsHandling.InvalidInputException: "userId" provided is invalid. It should be should be UUID]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    ...
```

I was hoping that since this POJO is used by the controller to parse request params, the custom exception could be caught.

If as a test I throw the custom `InvalidInputException` directly from the controller in the following way:

```
    @GetMapping("/highlights")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Highlight>> getHighlights(
            @Valid HighlightFilterCriteria highlightFilterCriteria
            ) {
        if (true) throw new InvalidInputException("userId", "should be UUID");
        ...
    }
```

Then I can see that the `InvalidInputException` handler catches it as expected.

```
INFO  com.hmhco.rcehighlightspoc.exceptionsHandling.GlobalExceptionHandler.handleInvalidInputException - Handled: Invalid input
com.hmhco.rcehighlightspoc.exceptionsHandling.InvalidInputException: "userId" provided is invalid. It should be should be UUID
    at com.hmhco.rcehighlightspoc.controller.HighlightController.getHighlights(HighlightController.java:63)
```

The main question is why `InvalidInputException` isn't caught by `ControllerAdvice`'s `InvalidInputException` exception handler but it is caught by `Exception` handler?

Or maybe I'm trying to achieve my validation in a POJO in an incorrect way, if so what would be the proper way to handle parsing errors for complex types like UUID and Date in ISO format when the controller method gets a POJO as an argument?

Comment: You might want to add more details to reproduce the error and what the error is? Some JSON you are sending, for example? As a generic answer to your question: add handler methods that handle also the possible parsing/constructor errors.

Comment: @pirho, I just edited the post to add more clarity. To make the long story short, the problem is that the `InvalidInputException` thrown from the POJO that is used to obtain request params in the controller isn't caught by the `InvalidInputException` ControllerAdvice handler. Instead it is caught by the catch all `Exception` handler. But if I throw the same `InvalidInputException` from inside of the controller, then it is cought by `InvalidInputException` handler as expected. I wonder why when it is thrown from the `HighlightFilterCriteria` it isn't caught in the same way as from controller.

Comment: I think this is kind a duplicate to your previous question I answered. The issue here - I think - is the same. Check what happens if you handle `org.springframework.validation.BindException`?

Comment: Spot on, thanks!

Just as a reference for anyone else, this is the referenced question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63969454/controlleradvice-isnt-picking-illegalargumentexception-thrown-by-an-incorrect-u/63971957?noredirect=1#comment113131851_63971957

If that POJO was implemented in such a way that I throw a different type of exceptions there and then I want to catch them in the ControllerAdvice and generate different type of responses to the user, then this is going to be a problem since all of them are `BindException`. Should I build the exception handler in a different way?